# For the line of code below I am getting "Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed" findbug.. How can this be resolved?

Tags: java, findbugs

```
Double a = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(x))
    .setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
```

`x` is of type `Double`, which I cannot change..

Comment: Why are `a` and `x` `Double`s, anyway? They probably ought to be primitive `double`s.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is of type `Double`, then `Double.valueOf(x)` is the cause of the warning. Just write `x` instead, which is already of the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

`Double.valueOf` takes a primitive `double` and returns a boxed `Double`, not the other way around. You're passing it a boxed `Double`, so `x` is autounboxed, then explicitly boxed by `Double.valueOf`, then autounboxed again to pass it to `new BigDecimal`. Just remove the `valueOf` call:

```
Double a = new BigDecimal(x).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
```

This will autounbox `x` once to pass it to the `BigDecimal` constructor.